# unknown file name change when file downloads

Tags: php, javascript, encryption, download

am using a script to download files from my site.

```
if (isset($_GET['file'])){
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    $query = "SELECT fileurl FROM dbname WHERE id='$file'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $filename = $row[fileurl];
    send_download($filename);
} 

function send_download($filename){
    $file_path = $filename;
    $file_size=@filesize($file_path);
    header("Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Length: $file_size");
    readfile($file_path);
    exit;
}
```

It works great but the only caveat is that the file name is changed to some encryted string ie **asdajkhasdkahdkasdakfsdhf.pdf** how do I change this so that it downloads with the original name??? And if possible, append + to the spaces inbetween the file name ie My+File.pdf

Comment: `var_dump($filename);` before u call `send_download` func which the name of file u are getting from DB and to rename the file you must rename at the time of uploading

Comment: I assume this is not your actual code? Because in your query you select a field called `fileurl` but then you try and pull value out of the first result row using `$row[path]`. That should be an integer not the word "path." Or if you use `mysql_fetch_assoc` it could be a key such as `$row['fileurl'] with quotes around it.

Comment: What you are doing is terribly insecure.  You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.  Making things worse, you are allowing users to get arbitrary files from your disk, which is a potential security problem as well.  **Always** validate the path first.  **Never** let the user specify a file name on your disk.  Keep users files out of the doc root, and with a file name you pick, such as an ID number or hash.

Comment: @Brad thats exactly why I posted this. So that people like you can inform me of the loopholes and help me correct em. I am pretty new to php and one of the books thats helped me get this far is one from Sitepoint! Am still learning though and thats why I keep coming here from time to time for help. So thank you for the feedback.